# Bootstrap alert dismissal not working, rails 3.2

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

using twitter bootstrap 2.0 with Rails 3.2 (css files in assets/stylesheets, not using less or sass right now)

I have an bootstrap styled error or success alert at the top of my screen (based on whether first word of message == "Error".
I've added 'bootstrap.js' & 'bootstrap-alert.js' to the assets/javascript folder.

Here is the code in my layout:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <% if msg[0..4] == "Error" %>
    <div class="alert alert-error fade in">
  <% else %>
    <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
  <% end %>
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
  <%= msg %>
<% end %>
```

In my assets/javascripts/application.js I have:

```
$(".alert-message").alert()
$(".alert-message").alert('close')
```

Not sure I need both? tried with .alert / .alert-error as well.

Nothing happens when I click the close symbol, I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious, but I'm new to using JS /w Rails, can't figure this out.
In the Chrome JS console I see this error message, which seems to be about bootstrap-alert.js data-api:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'`

Many thanks for any tips!

Comment: Seconds after clicking 'submit' on this question you realise the problem... The problem was caused by having 'jquery.js' and 'jquiery-ui.js' also in the javascripts folder, must be having clashing names/classes. After removing the jquiery files the js error disappeared on loading the page and the alert-dismissal works now... d'oh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in comments, the problem seems to have been caused by competing Javascript files.

The problem was caused by having 'jquery.js' and 'jquery-ui.js' also in the Javascripts folder, must be having clashing names/classes.

After removing the jQuery files the js error disappeared on loading the page and the alert-dismissal works now

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue, and looked at your answer bobomoreno, but it didn't work. I later found out that the newest version of Bootstrap requires [jQuery 1.7.x](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/862) and doesn't work with older versions of jQuery.

Comment: I updated my Gemfile to specify `gem jquery-rails ~> '2.0'` (which gets jQ 1.7.x) but still not getting the close event to fire. :-(

Comment: I don't know anything about rails, but have you updated the client reference as well to point to the new jQuery version?

Comment: Agree. Replacing 1.6.4.min with 1.7.2.min fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem - alert dismissal did not work for me. Solution was similar to bobomoreno's, but not the same. I had a file `app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js.coffee` with some custom stuff, which was required instead of bootstrap's javascripts. I fixed it by changing name to `bootstrap-custom.js.coffee`, so bootstrap's files was properly required.

Comment: This was my answer, and it actually makes sense.  Moving around jquery and jquery versions is a red herring.